# Script allowing me to telnet to several IP clocks at once to issue one command

Tags: powershell, scripting, telnet

I am not a script guy, actually have never written a script before. I work in a large warehouse where there are dozens of IP clocks mounted all over the place. If we loose power, or sometimes just out of the blue, the clocks loose their time. I have to telnet into each one and issue a command to bring them back up. I'd like to learn to write simple code, but don't know where to start. Can someone use this to show me how to write a simple telnet command with user/pass so I can fix these clocks all at once?

Comment: A well-written question, but this forum is not for training. You should give it a try, and if your attempt does not work then post your code, tell us what happened (including the full text of any error messages) and you should get some useful advice.

Comment: I agree with Kimbert, but I'll be nice and give you a place to get started: https://aventistech.com/perform-automate-telnet-commands-with-powershell/. This post explains how to get a set of cmdlets that can issue telnet commands (among other things). Try to adapt this for your needs and edit your question if you have problems making this work.

Comment: Thanks y'all, I'll see what I can come up with.